# Hard Disk disappears after a long sleep time

Tags: hard-drive, sleep, ahci, ubuntu-22.04

Recently everytime the laptop is in sleep mode for a long time the HDD does not show up anymore. But after a reboot it shows up as usual.

I have a dual disk setup with the OS in the SSD. The HDD model is **WDC WD10SPZX-24Z10**. Recently whenever the laptop is in sleep mode for a long time the hard disk just disappears. It doesn't show up in the file system or Gparted. I called `lsblk` and `fdisk -l` but both only showed the snap partitions and the partitions in the SSD. The only way to make the HDD reappear is rebooting the laptop. After that it appears as usual. It is present in the BIOS and in **AHCI** mode.

I have researched the problem and most similar problems are from Windows based systems and the solutions seem to be about Intel RST. But my HDD is not using RST tech either. I could really use any help and suggestions.

Edit: - [SMART data and self test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QTff.png)

Comment: How old is the disk ?

Comment: The Disk is almost 3 years old and came with the laptop.

Comment: Please add to your post a screenshot of the SMART attributes of the disk.